# Is it possible to edit the website within an iframe?

Tags: iframe

I'd like to limit how much of the website, within the iframe tag, will be visible. Is that possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.lipsum.com/" width="300" height="300">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width and height of an iframe to configure how much of the website will be visible at one time, but making the width and height smaller than the width and height of the embedded website will just cause scrollbars to appear so the user can scroll to see the whole website.

An iframe is designed to show the whole of whatever is in the src tag, so you can't use it to just show specific parts of that website (i.e. just the content area and not the navigation or footer), if that's what you're asking.